# Writing integer values to spreadsheet

Tags: ruby

I am using the following code to convert a csv to spreadsheet:

```
require 'spreadsheet'
require 'csv'

book = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
sheet1 = book.create_worksheet

CSV.open("product_2014-11-19_10-41-00.csv", 'r') do |csv|
    csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
        sheet1.row(i).replace(row)
    end
end
book.write("temp.xls")
```

But on doing so, the spreadsheet contains a leading quote for columns that hold integer values. Eg consider the row `SGDEL,18,,,,140,0,Bib` columns corresponding to 18, 140 and 0 become '18, '140, '0. Why is this so? How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing the format of those columns to int

Comment: @HanaBizhani: What if I dont know what all columns would be integers?

Answer (score 2):

There is an option for [CSV#open](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-new):

```
#                    vvvvvvvvvvvv 
CSV.open("…", "…", { force_quotes: false }) do |csv|
```

Setting it to `false` should do the trick.